# javamail multiple attachment with gui

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-mail

Trying to do a basic mail sender app with GUI, but no matter what I do cannot send/add multiple
attachments (tried most of the answers in old Stack Overflow questions - didn't work, 
I don't want to add manually "multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);" for every attachment. Is there a way to add multiple attachments without repeating code over and over again ). what am I missing, what is wrong? (full GUI photo added as an attachment and red words are variable names 
link =  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVVc9.png )

```
try 
        {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(FromMail));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(ToMail));
            message.setSubject(SubjectMail);
            //message.setText(ContentMail);
            
            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setText(ContentMail);
            
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
            
            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(AttachmentPath);
            
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            messageBodyPart.setFileName(attachment_name.getText());
            
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
                        
            message.setContent(multipart);
            
            Transport.send(message);
            
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "success, message sent!");
        } 
        catch (Exception exp) 
        {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, exp);
        }
}

private void attachmentActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
        
        Component frame = null;
        chooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
        
        File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        AttachmentPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        
        //path_attachment.setText(AttachmentPath);
        path_attachment_area.setText(AttachmentPath);
    } 

String AttachmentPath;
```

Comment: _tried most of the answers in old Stack Overflow questions - didn't work_ can you please show exactly what you tried? In your current code there is nothing that tries to send multiple attachment.

Comment: like this, ```Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("mixed");
            
            for (String str : attachment_PathList) {
            
                MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                DataSource source = new FileDataSource(str);
                messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
                messageBodyPart.setFileName(source.getName());
                multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
            
            }
            
            message.setContent(multipart);
            Transport.send(message);```

Comment: or this,  ```MimeBodyPart messageAttachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
  
 for (String attachment_name: file) {
            messageAttachmentPart.attachFile(attachment_name);
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageAttachmentPart);
        }
```

Comment: The problem is in the file selection, you pick only a single file from the JFileChooser, so other selected files will be not considered. The code in the comments above looks correct.

Comment: but when i try to add them in a string[] array or ArrayList<> i got error

Answer (score 0):

This is a minimal GUI with two buttons, Attach and Send, and a textarea to collect selected files, I didn't replicate your complete GUI, so you have to integrate it in your code.

Actually you only have to check `onAttach()` that is selecting the attachments and `onSend()` where a for loop adds all selected attachments to the message.

Note also that the textarea is only used to display the selected files, but the file list is kept in an ArrayList.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class TestEmail extends JPanel {

    String fromEmail = "myemail@mydomain.com";
    String toEmail = "destmail@anotherdomain.com";

    protected JButton attachButton=new JButton("Add attachment(s)");
    protected JButton sendButton=new JButton("Send");
    protected JTextArea attachmentsArea=new JTextArea(10, 30);
    protected JFileChooser chooser=new JFileChooser();
    
    protected List<File> attachments=new ArrayList<File>();

    public TestEmail() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        attachmentsArea.setEditable(false);
        chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);

        JScrollPane scrollPane=new JScrollPane(attachmentsArea);
        add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        Box buttonPanel=new Box(BoxLayout.X_AXIS);
        buttonPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        buttonPanel.add(attachButton);
        buttonPanel.add(sendButton);
        
        add(buttonPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        attachButton.addActionListener((e)->onAttach());
        sendButton.addActionListener((e)->onSend());
    }

    public Session getSession() {
        final String password = "mypassword";
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.mydomain.com"); // SMTP Host
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); // enable authentication
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");  
        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
            // override the getPasswordAuthentication method
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(fromEmail, password);
            }
        };

        return Session.getInstance(props, auth);
    }

    public void onAttach() {
        if (chooser.showOpenDialog(this)==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            for (File f: chooser.getSelectedFiles()) {
                if (!f.isDirectory()&&!attachments.contains(f)) {
                    attachments.add(f);
                    attachmentsArea.append(f.getAbsolutePath()+"\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void onSend() {
        try {
            Session session = getSession();
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(toEmail));
            message.setSubject("A subject");
    
            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setText("Dummy message, just to send attachments.");
    
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    
            for (File f: attachments) {
                MimeBodyPart part=new MimeBodyPart();
                part.attachFile(f);
                multipart.addBodyPart(part);
            }
            message.setContent(multipart);
            Transport.send(message);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Message successfully sent", "Success", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Exception sending e-mail:\n"+ex.getMessage(),"Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(()->{
            JFrame frame=new JFrame("Sendmail");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setContentPane(new TestEmail());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```